# Accessing information in array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, fetch

Ok Im getting a bit confused with arrays in php. This is the code

```
$search = "%" . $search ."%";
// Step 1: Establish a connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=########", "#########", "###########");

// Step 2: Construct a query
$query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE " . $db->quote($search);

// Step 3: Send the query
$result = $db->query($query);

// Step 4: Iterate over the results
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
    echo $row['title'];
}

// Step 5: Free used resources
$result->closeCursor();
$db = null;
```

Now when I search for say "Candyman" it returns 6 results, what I am tring to do is something like `$row['title'][3]` (So I can grab the title of the 3rd film in the array)
however this doesn't work `$row['title'];` displays all 6 titles how do I access the next level?

Below is a link to the search I am using
http://www.gorrors.com/moviesearch.php?search=candyman

Sorry for the newbie question but Im at a loss any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query, like, `$query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE " . $db->quote($search);` use limit, `$query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE " . $db->quote($search) limit $start,$numbers;` http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
echo $row[3]['title']'
```

PDO::query:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Which returns a PDOStatement object:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

...which has a method named fetchAll(), which returns an array of all the rows, which by default you can access using either numeric indexes or strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [*Grouping all values by a single column*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1023)  :

```
//do not use * in your sql if you only need the imfromation of movie title 
$query = "SELECT title FROM movies WHERE title LIKE " . $db->quote($search);

$result = $dbh->prepare($query);
$result->execute();

$row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
var_dump($row); 
//$row['title'][2] will give the third result,not $row['title'][3]
```